# What sort of function is this? (Logistic map?)

Tags: fractals

What sort of function is this? This looks like a bifurcation diagram of a logistic map to me, but there seem to be extra parameters that are changed along with the different colours, what are these?

[image: Fractal-like picture]

Comment: Where did you find this diagram ?

Comment: I got it from a blog, which didn't explain anything, but after a reverse image search it seems that the source of the diagram is this: https://bio.m2osw.com/gcartable/bifurcation.htm, but it is in french.

Comment: Thanks. No problem with french, but in fact there is nothing explaining 1) the reason of these colors and 2) the presence of these uncommon "threads" in a bifurcation diagram.

Comment: This seems to represent the whole sequences $(x_n)$ vs $a$, not only the limit points of $(x_n)$ vs $a$ as usual, for $x_{n+1}=ax_n(1-x_n)$ and $x_0=0.0001$, for $a$ from about $1.5$ (on the left) to $4.2$ (on the right). Thus, one of these vaguely paraboloid lines in red is the graph of, say, $x_{7}$ vs $a$, another one is the graph of $x_{13}$ vs $a$, and so on. And each color might correspond to some specific $n$. More or less... :-)